# LinkedIn Share button not scraping image or content for share

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, linkedin-api, social-media

I'm trying to add social media share/like buttons to a web page, the share functionality is working but I'm finding that no image or description is being scraped from the page.

I have been setting open graph meta tags but that doesn't have any affect, I've raised the issue with LinkedIn but haven't had any correspondence back from them:

https://developer.linkedin.com/forum/share-button-not-reading-open-graph-metatags

I'm using the HTML5 doctype and html opener tag with appropriate namespaces and the JSESSIONID cookie is not being set:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8" session="false"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">
```

Here's the implementation of the button:

```
<script src="http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="IN/Share" data-url="<%=shortUrl%>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    document.getElementById("fands-include-photo").setAttribute("value", "false");
    $( window ).ready( function() {
        $( '.IN-widget' ).click( function() {
            _gaq.push( [ '_trackSocial', 'LinkedIn', 'Share', '<%=shortUrl%>' ] );
        });
    });
</script>
```

I have tried calling undocumented methods from the LinkedIn plugin API like IN.init() and IN.parse() but that doesn't seem to make any difference.
Looking at the console in Firebug there are no javascript errors or warnings...

I've created a test page to demonstrate the problem:
http://www.claytonutz.com/publications/testSocialMedia.jsp

Any help is much appreciated, thanks in advance!
Chris.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is likely that the data is cached from a previous share of this page. The cache is flushed on a periodic basis, but there is (unfortunately) no way for you to force us to flush the cache for you.

That's a known limitation and is on the feature request list.

Comment: Hey Adam, I ended up tweaking AddThis to do what I need and am happy to report that it is working perfectly now. That cache flushing feature sounds like a great idea. Thanks.